# How to change one link in a Woocommerce breadcrumbs?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I need to change one link in a woocommerce breadcrumbs:

> Home > example1 > **example2** > example3
>
> example2 is going to /product-category/products/example2/ but  I need
> to modify this link with a customized page:  e.g.
> /mypersonalproducts/mypage

I tried with "Code Snippets" plug-in in wordpress this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_get_breadcrumb', 20, 2 );
function custom_get_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $crumbs; // Only shop page

    // The Crump item to target
    $target = __( 'example2', 'woocommerce' );

    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        if( $target === $crumb[0] ){
            // 1. Change name
            $crumbs[$key][0] = __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' );

            // 2. Change URL (you can also use get_permalink( $id ) with the post Id
            $crumbs[$key][1] = home_url( '/mypersonalproducts/mypage' );
        }
    }
    return $crumbs;
}
```

and this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_breadcrumb', 10, 2 );
function custom_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $object_class ){
    // Loop through all $crumb
    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // The product category taxonomy

        // Check if it is a product category term
        $term_array = term_exists( $crumb[0], $taxonomy );

        // if it is a product category term
        if ( $term_array !== 0 && $term_array !== null ) {

            // Get the WP_Term instance object
            $term = get_term( $term_array['example2'], $taxonomy );

            // HERE set your new link with a custom one
            $crumbs[$key][1] = home_url( '/mypersonalproducts/mypage' ); // or use all other dedicated functions
        }
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

But it didn't work